# Свой пункт в контекстном меню Windows

Tags: c#, .net

При установке новых программ, при нажатии правой кнопки мыши и выборе в меню создать можно выбрать создаваемый файл этой программой.

Например, после установки Office можно создать какой-нибудь Excel из контекстного меню Windows.

А некоторые программы вообще могут создать новый пункт, например, как на скриншоте появился пункт меню AMD.

Как моя программа может попасть в этот раздел если она имеет свой формат файлов?

Я подозреваю, что нужно прописаться куда-то в реестр и должен быть вызов метода Main с определенным аргументом по которому будет создан файл, но что-то не смог нагулить подробностей.

Вот это имею ввиду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, судя по всему, ассоциации файлов?

Comment: Не, дополнил скриншотом.

Comment: А, так это не _при_ установке Office, а _после_ неё?

Comment: Да, подправил вопрос.

Comment: Тогда судя по всему вам сюда: https://superuser.com/a/46952. Только в реестр нужно писать прямо, а не через .reg-файл, разумеется.

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23052139/276994 (но это продвинутые сценарии)

Comment: @VladD, оформите как ответ.

Comment: Правда, при переходи в директорию с шаблонами я не смог найти там шаблоны архивов WinRar(Ваша первая ссылка). Получается, что он реализует механизм второй ссылки?

Answer (score 1):

Нужную информацию проще всего найти в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx#extend_new_shortcut_menu).

Для того, чтобы добавить обработчик `New...` для зарегистрированного типа вашего приложения, вы должны зарегистрировать расширение, и для него установить в инсталляторе подключ `ShellNew`. Если вы не делаете инсталлятор, то в ключе для вашего расширения (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.расш`) укажите подключ `ShellNew`. В нём создайте значение, которое указывает, как именно будет создаваться новый файл.

У вас есть 4 возможности.

- Значение `Command` строкового типа (`REG_SZ`, `string` с точки зрения C#). Будет вызвана ваша команда, путь к которой указан вами в значении параметра.
- Значение `Data` бинарного типа (`REG_BINARY`, `byte[]` с точки зрения C#). Данные будут скопированы в новый файл.
- Значение `FileName` строкового типа. Поместите сюда имя файла, и он будет скопирован. Не забудьте добавить и сам файл. Если этот ключ указан, ключ `Data` игнорируется.
- Значение `NullFile` (пустой). Создаётся пустой файл. Если этот ключ указан, ключи `Data` и `FileName` игнорируются.

При указании имени файла в `FileName`, вы можете либо указать полное имя (тогда оно используется), либо, кажется можно указать относительный путь. При этом поиск проводится сначала в `%USERPROFILE%\Templates` текущего пользователя, затем в `%ALLUSERPROFILE%\Templates`, а затем в `%SYSTEMROOT%\ShellNew`.